# Quadrant plot based on ccf value outputs in R

Tags: r, plot, cross-correlation

I'm trying to make a plot of species sensitivity and response speed to discharge. I need the max lag position as a x value, and the correlation of that lag position as the y value.

I have this sample data...

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16222, 16617, 14518, 15156, 
15918, 17075, 15522, 16679, 16010, 15187, 15461, 16283, 17379, 
15553, 17410, 15553, 16191, 16314, 14549, 15979), class = "Date"), 
    Commonname = c("Black Sea Bass", "Pinfish", "Pigfish", "Pinfish", 
    "Silver Perch", "Black Sea Bass", "Pigfish", "Pinfish", "Pigfish", 
    "Silver Perch", "Silver Perch", "Black Sea Bass", "Pinfish", 
    "Pinfish", "Silver Perch", "Pigfish", "Black Sea Bass", "Silver Perch", 
    "Silver Perch", "Black Sea Bass"), CPUE = c(1.25513090974505, 
    9.41478783154444, 1.63667465565289, 3.13779141143018, 4.26313144106683, 
    2.32564938844104, 2.70394855189782, 8.49969670589948, 1.7329255861366, 
    2.0845409179642, 0.269832703723692, 1.21288437532366, 11.8739506505966, 
    8.55504246458105, 2.21256794002004, 4.51336797979511, 1.47695928524315, 
    1.10425042966867, 0.632732705722451, 1.59167844861806), Discharge = c(14.8521616, 
    5.23042759111111, 1.42663083211115, 0.184551018105263, 48.9156538971429, 
    2.29765846588235, 33.25524992, 4.06629248, 1.610659584, 0.21166808, 
    0.0607489749333333, 2.22029454545455, 12.90821328, 31.9696672, 
    8.05754544, 32.7267690105263, 43.493472128, 6.77337856, 1.10646621744, 
    4.37803470545454)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'm using this code to plot all the ccf functions...

```
df.split <- split(df, df$Commonname, drop = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(3,4))
lapply(seq_along(df.split), function(x) ccf(df.split[[x]]$CPUE,df.split[[x]]$Discharge, lag.max = 5,
                                              ylab = "", xlab = "", main= names(df.split)[x]))
```

But what is need is to extract those values for each species and get them into vectors so i can plot them on some sort of quantile plot.

My ideal output would be a plot in which the x axis would be from 0-5 or whatever I as `lag.max` (in the code above its 5). The y axis would be from -1 to 1 (unless 0 to 1 with the absolute value of the correlation makes more sense).

The code above outputs the values in the console and plots the ccf function for all species included in the split, but I have ~130 species and it would be too tedious to fill in the values manually.

so it would look something like this... Where each species would have one point. Would be labeled with the species name. And as a bonus would have an * by the name is the lag correlation value (`y`) was significant. Again the x value would be the lag with the highest correlation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear @Johnny5ish I'll try to help you. However, at the beginning I have to admit that I do not know what the `ccf` function is and and what does it return. Nevertheless, I am convinced that I will be able to show you how to approach this task.

Let's start with the data in the `df` variable.
I divided everything into 4 simple steps. I will describe in turn what they give.

```
library(tidyverse)

fccf = function(data) ccf(data$CPUE,data$Discharge, lag.max = 5, plot = FALSE)
facf = function(acf) tibble(aacf = acf$acf[,,1], lag = acf$lag[,,1])

df %>% group_by(Commonname) %>%
  nest() %>%  #Step 1
  mutate(ccf = map(data, ~fccf(.x))) %>% #Step 2
  mutate(acf = map(ccf, ~facf(.x))) %>%  #Step 3
  unnest(acf) %>%  #Step 4
  ggplot(aes(lag, aacf, fill=Commonname, color=Commonname))+
  geom_point()
```

Step 1.
I group the data of the variable `Commonname` and fold it with the function `nest`.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   Commonname [4]
  Commonname     data            
  <chr>          <list>          
1 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]>
2 Pinfish        <tibble [5 x 3]>
3 Pigfish        <tibble [4 x 3]>
4 Silver Perch   <tibble [6 x 3]>
```

Step. 2
I am using a simple `fccf` function which will return the results of the `ccf` function to a variable with the same name.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Commonname [4]
  Commonname     data             ccf   
  <chr>          <list>           <list>
1 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf> 
2 Pinfish        <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf> 
3 Pigfish        <tibble [4 x 3]> <acf> 
4 Silver Perch   <tibble [6 x 3]> <acf>
```

Step 3
I use the `facf` function which converts the output of the `ccf` function to `tibble`. Modify this function according to your needs.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Commonname [4]
  Commonname     data             ccf    acf              
  <chr>          <list>           <list> <list>           
1 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>  <tibble [9 x 2]> 
2 Pinfish        <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>  <tibble [9 x 2]> 
3 Pigfish        <tibble [4 x 3]> <acf>  <tibble [7 x 2]> 
4 Silver Perch   <tibble [6 x 3]> <acf>  <tibble [11 x 2]>
```

As you can see, we have a very neat `tibble` here with all the intermediate steps of the calculation. In Step 4, I develop the results that interest me with the `unnest` function.

```
# A tibble: 36 x 5
# Groups:   Commonname [4]
   Commonname     data             ccf         aacf   lag
   <chr>          <list>           <list>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>   0.0911      -4
 2 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>  -0.518       -3
 3 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>   0.932       -2
 4 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>  -0.470       -1
 5 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>  -0.248        0
 6 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>   0.213        1
 7 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>   0.0109       2
 8 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>  -0.0110       3
 9 Black Sea Bass <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>   0.000854     4
10 Pinfish        <tibble [5 x 3]> <acf>   0.146       -4
# ... with 26 more rows
```

And such data is easy to create on a nice plot using the `ggplot2` package.
[image]

Here, I crossed out the `acf` values in the `lag` function with the breakdown into individual `Commonname` groups.

Perhaps this is not the kind of graph you expected. However, I hope that, already knowing the correct and simple path, you will be able to adjust it to your needs. If you have any questions, write in the comment. Good luck!

**Update 1**
You can do like this

```
df %>% group_by(Commonname) %>%
  nest() %>%  #1
  mutate(ccf = map(data, ~fccf(.x))) %>% #2
  mutate(acf = map(ccf, ~facf(.x))) %>%  #3
  unnest(acf) %>%  #4
  ggplot(aes(lag, aacf, fill = Commonname, colour = Commonname))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(label = Commonname), 
             size=3.5, alpha = 0.6, colour = "black",
             hjust = 1, vjust = 1)
```

[image]
Or this way

```
...  geom_label(aes(label = Commonname), 
             size=3.5, alpha = 0.2, colour = "black",
             hjust = 1, vjust = 1)
```

[image]
Or anything else. The `ggplot2` package is amazing in this regard!

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I can work with this. I was looking for one point per species, but I can just weight all 10 lags (positive 5 and minus 5) using the correlation value. Then I can take the mean of those for my x value. For y value I think I can simple mean the correlation values. The last thing i was looking for is the name of the species by each point on the plot instead of a legend since there are about 133 species.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: If my solution helped you, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Hello sir, you have helped tremendously, but i have run into an issue. Could you please take a look at my follow up question. I'm having some issues with the values your custom functions are pulling.  please take a look if you have time.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877821/wrong-values-collected-from-custom-ccf-function-in-r